# How do I change the input result to integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
inp_name = input('Please input your name - ')
print('Welcome', inp_name)
inp_height = input('Please input your height in metre - ')
inp_weight = input('Please input your weight in kg - ')
print(inp_name, ', your bmi is :')
bmi = int(inp_weight)/(int(inp_height) ** 2)
print(bmi)
```

Comment: you also maybe want to think about do you want int or float. Int is a whole number so for height you could be 1m or 2m. If you want to be 1.73m then you need to use floats

Answer (score -1):

Simply add "int" infront of where you are asking for inputs, like so:

```
inp_name = str(input('Please input your name - '))
print('Welcome', inp_name)
inp_height = int(input('Please input your height in metre - '))
inp_weight = int(input('Please input your weight in kg - '))
print(inp_name, ', your bmi is :')
bmi = int(inp_weight)/(int(inp_height) ** 2)
print(bmi)
```

You can see that I have also added `str` on the first line, this will make it so the user can only input a string. You can also ask for a float by adding `float`, like this: `float(input("Input a float: "))`.

**EDIT:** Furthermore, if a user doesn't input the data type you are asking for, an error will occur:

[image]

You can stop this error by adding a "try: except:":

```
try:
    inp_height = int(input("Please input your height in metres: "))
    print(inp_height)

except: 
    print("Enter the correct data type")
```

*This will catch any errors that happen.*

Comment: Putting `str(...)` around `input(...)` accomplishes nothing. `input` always returns a string.

Comment: @khelwood Ah okay! I honestly thought this but I thought it was best practice just to use str() when you want a string input. I guess you can use "if variable str:" to accept strings as inputs. Thank you for your comment though, always good to learn these things!